# Little problem with element attribute in .xml file (Python)

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to replace "cooling cid=1" element with "cooling cid=2" element. So I dit that using `myroot[0][0]=myroot[0][1]`but when I want to replace the first "cid" value with "cid=1", it change also the cid value on the second element.

I would also like do delete `<cooling cid="2">`but it doesn't work with `myroot.remove(myroot[0][1])`

How can I achieve that?

Input :

```
<compositionhistory type="result" iteration="1">
    <compositiondata tid="6">
                <cooling cid="1">
                    <isotope zamid="10010">3.776028e-09</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="30060">2.851899e-09</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="30070">2.253752e-10</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="30080">7.533722e-18</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="30090">1.172801e-18</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="40060">6.672459e-39</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="40080">1.084507e-33</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="40090">8.142463e-11</isotope>
                 </cooling>
                <cooling cid="2">
                    <isotope zamid="10010">3.776028e-09</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="30060">2.851899e-09</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="30070">2.253752e-10</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="40090">8.142463e-11</isotope>
                </cooling>
      </compositiondata>
</compositionhistory>
```

Code :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
  
mytree = ET.parse('input2.xml') #open file
myroot = mytree.getroot()

for child in myroot[0]:         
    print(child.attrib)

myroot[0][0]=myroot[0][1] # paste "cid2" element on "cid=1"
myroot[0][1].set("cid", "1") # here is the problem. I want to rename only the first element and keep cid=2 on the second element

for child in myroot[0]:
    print(child.attrib)
    
mytree.write('output2.xml')
```

Output :

```
<compositionhistory iteration="1" type="result">
    <compositiondata tid="6">
                <cooling cid="1">
                    <isotope zamid="10010">3.776028e-09</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="30060">2.851899e-09</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="30070">2.253752e-10</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="40090">8.142463e-11</isotope>
                </cooling>
      <cooling cid="1">                                          # here it should be cid=2 not cid=1
                    <isotope zamid="10010">3.776028e-09</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="30060">2.851899e-09</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="30070">2.253752e-10</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="40090">8.142463e-11</isotope>
                </cooling>
      </compositiondata>
</compositionhistory
```

Comment: Try `myroot[0][0] = copy.deepcopy(myroot[0][1])`. Don't forget to `import copy`.

Comment: Another option - ugly, but no importing: `myroot[0][0] = ET.fromstring(ET.tostring(myroot[0][1]))`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) of the original element and it should work:

```
import copy

myroot[0][0]=copy.deepcopy(myroot[0][1])
```

The modification only shows on the original element:

```
myroot[0][0].set("cid", "1") # I believe you only want to rename the first
```

Printing the resulting element:

```
In [92]: print(ET.tostring(myroot).decode())
<compositionhistory iteration="1" type="result">
    <compositiondata tid="6">
                <cooling cid="1">
                    <isotope zamid="10010">3.776028e-09</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="30060">2.851899e-09</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="30070">2.253752e-10</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="40090">8.142463e-11</isotope>
                </cooling>
      <cooling cid="2">
                    <isotope zamid="10010">3.776028e-09</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="30060">2.851899e-09</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="30070">2.253752e-10</isotope>
                    <isotope zamid="40090">8.142463e-11</isotope>
                </cooling>
      </compositiondata>
</compositionhistory>
```